# How to call an apex class exposed as SOAP webservice from Postman

Tags: apex, integration, webservices, soap, postman

I have an apex class **soapServiceClass**

```
global with sharing class soapServiceClass{
    //Based on this parameter, it returns the account information
    webService static Account getAccountRecord(string accid){
                Account acc = [select id, name, type, AccountNumber,  Rating, AnnualRevenue  from account 
                                   where id=:accid];
                return acc;
    }
}
```

I am trying to call it from postman and getting error as below after sending this in postman

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                     xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/soapServiceClass">
       <soapenv:Header >
           <SessionHeader>**SESSION ID**</sessionId>
           </SessionHeader>
       </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body>
           <getAccountRecord>
               <accid>**ACC ID**</accid>
           </getAccountRecord>
       </soapenv:Body>

</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**ERROR :-**

```
<soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>No operation available for request {http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/soapServiceClass}getAccountRecord</faultstring>
        </soapenv:Fault>
```

URL to hit :- https://abc.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/58.0/00D56000000N6b5 ~ replaced abc with actual name

Trying to test the scenario from this blogpost https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/how-to-expose-apex-class-as-a-soap-service-in-postman-salesforce-developer-guide/ but it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL is not correct. The URL should be as below. Replace the `<My Domain Name>` with yours. You can get this by visiting *Setup > Company Settings > My Domain > My Domain Name*.

```
https://<My Domain Name>.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/class/soapServiceClass
```